# How can I make a change to every newly created table in our Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We need to add a table-specific Postgres function and sequence to every table in our database. I am wondering if there is a best/easy way to ensure that the necessary function and sequence are created each time a table is created in the future. We are using PostgreSQL 9.2 and Rails 3.2.

Comment: You could derive or monkey patch `ActiveRecord::Migration` and overwrite `up` and/or `down`.

Comment: Have you considered database triggers?

Comment: @MrDanA, I thought about that, but PG doesn't allow you to create a trigger that will run on table creation: "PostgreSQL only allows the execution of a user-defined function for the triggered action. The standard allows the execution of a number of other SQL commands, such as CREATE TABLE, as the triggered action. This limitation is not hard to work around by creating a user-defined function that executes the desired commands."  I am not sure if "creating a user-defined function" is the best way to approach this, or start mucking with the ActiveRecord migrations as ckruse suggested.